# Do spiritual beings come to people in a dream or are they projected into the mind's capability to imagine?

Tags: genesis, matthew, dream

All passages in RSV (Revised Standard Version).

> But God came to Abim′elech in a dream by night, and said to him (...)
> Genesis 20:3

> Then the angel of God said to me in the dream, ‘Jacob,’ and I said,
> ‘Here I am!’ (...) Genesis 31:11

> But God came to Laban the Aramean in a dream by night, and said to
> him, “Take heed that you say not a word to Jacob, either good or bad.”
> Genesis 31:24
>
> At Gibeon the Lord appeared to Solomon in a dream by night; and God
> said, “Ask what I shall give you.” 1 Kings 3:5

> But as he considered this, behold, an angel of the Lord appeared to
> him in a dream, saying, (...) Matthew 1:20

> The Escape to Egypt Now when they had departed, behold, an angel of
> the Lord appeared to Joseph in a dream and said, (...) Matthew 2:13

Humans have in the mind/spirit the ability to form images with or without motion and visualize them internally, this can be done in an awaken state (imagine a dolphin holding an apple). 
Some dreams stated in the Bible weren't quite clear and needed someone else to interpret them (Daniel). God gave Daniel Nebuchadnezzar dreams interpretation, which shows that God knows everything even what men dream.

About these verses, is it a plain spiritual being coming to the persons spirit/mind when they are asleep or is it God projecting imagery in their imagination faculty?

I ask this because, if it is the former, then dreams indeed may have a connection to the spiritual world and beings, apart from the persons own mind projecting imagery.

If the latter, or some other interpretation, then there isn't much else to deepen in the knowledge in this particular subject.

What is the best interpretation for these verses?

Answer (score 1):

The OP's question lists a number of excellent examples of divine messages being delivered to people via visions or dreams.  There are many more examples in the Bible.  In such cases, the information is conveyed directly to the recipient's mind, either while they are asleep or during waking time.

However, this does not prevent God also delivering messages by personal visits of spirit beings such as:

- Matt 28:5 - an angel instructs the women at the tomb
- Luke 1:11 - the angel (Gabriel) appears to Zechariah
- Luke 1:26-28 - angel Gabriel delivers a message to Mary
- 1 Kings 19:5-8 - an angel appears to Elijah twice to feed him food.
- Ex 3:2 - the angel of the LORD appeared to Moses at the burning bush
- Judges 13:3, 9, 21 - the angel of the LORD appeared to Manoah and his wife
- Judges 6:12 - the angel of the LORD appeared to Gideon
- Josh 5:13-15 - the commander of the LORD's army appears to Joshua

There is a simple difference between these two types of divine revelation:

- In one, the record simply says something like, "an angel appeared to XXX in a dream/vision"
- In a physical appearance, the record says something like, "an angel appeared to XXX"

This is consistent with the statement in Heb 1:1 -

> On many past occasions and in many different ways, God spoke to our
> fathers through the prophets.

That is, God speaks to humans in a variety of ways.

Answer (score 0):

"And the LORD said to them, “Now listen to what I say: “If there were prophets among you, I, the LORD, would reveal myself in visions. I would speak to them in dreams" (Numbers 12:6)!

When God chose me, I LITERALLY heard the voice of God call me three times as He did Samuel (I Samuel 3) that I didn't know was in Scripture at the time until an old classmate saw me on Facebook and asked if we were from the same High School, called me.  After I told her about how He called me, she told me that's the same way He chose Samuel.

Afterwards I had the most HORRIFIC dream one could imagine that was also in Scripture that I didn't realize at the time until I 'accidentally' opened my Bible to Daniel Chapter 4 and saw " Nevertheless leave the stump of his roots in the earth, even with a band of iron and brass, in the tender grass of the field; and let it be wet with the dew of heaven, and let his portion be with the beasts in the grass of the earth:" which was my dream that I call "Trees Popping" wherein trees were popping midway their trunk but "remained embedded in the earth" (Daniel 4:15) and trees are a metaphor for men,"...trees of righteousness" (Isaiah 61)!

Comment: What are you talking about "Provide detailed answers to this question, including citations and an explanation of why your answer is correct...?"  Didn't the Word of God give the answer when the question was "Do spiritual beings come to people in a dream or are they projected into the mind's capability to imagine?" and God said "He sends visions and dreams" with Numbers 12:6 "cited?"  YOU HATE GOD (Exodus 20:5)!

Answer (score 0):

#### Do spiritual beings come to people in [dreams or] the mind's [imagination]?

Probable Answer: **Both**.

Let us look at a couple of the examples stated in the OP:

> **Genesis 31:11-12**: “Then the angel of God said to me in the dream, ‘Jacob,’ and I said, ‘Here I am.’ *He said*, ‘Lift up now your eyes and see that all the male goats...'"

Here, Jacob may have been day dreaming or in a trance, but it is undeniable that God spoke to him recognizably. After all, Jacob was told to "lift up his eyes" to "see the goats." The text tells us that "[God] said." This is not merely Jacob's imagination. People often have vivid imaginations, but this is something quite different.

Suppose we consider verses from Matthew (part of the OP):

> **Matthew 1:20**: "But when he had considered this, behold, an angel of the Lord appeared to him in a dream, saying, 'Joseph, son of David, do not be afraid to take Mary as your wife; for the Child who has been conceived in her is of the Holy Spirit.'"

Joseph is commanded by God to take Mary as his wife. These cannot be merely fleeting, imaginative reflections; it was *crucial* for Joseph to obey. Similarly,

> **Matthew 2:13**: "Now when [the magi] had gone, behold, an angel of the Lord appeared to Joseph in a dream and said, 'Get up! Take the Child and His mother and flee to Egypt, and remain there until I tell you; for Herod is going to search for the Child to destroy Him.'”

Immediate action was vital. This is not the result of someone's imagination, but a clear directive from deity: a special revelation from God just as with Matt. 1:20.
God can certainly read our minds as suggested in the OP. He "knows the thoughts and intentions of the heart," which is another way of conveying the same idea (1 Cor. 2:11, Psa. 94:11, 1 Kgs. 8:39, Jer. 17:10, etc.).

Anyone might imagine having such thoughts or dreams, but the text reads "an angel of the Lord *appeared to him* in a dream." We often read such language in the Bible. It must be, as with the prophet Micaiah, that there really is a vision of the angelic, not merely some fanciful imaginative idea. We see this with the prophet Micaiah:

> **1 Kings 22:20-21**: “Micaiah said, 'Therefore, hear the word of the LORD. *I saw the LORD sitting on His throne, and all the host of heaven standing by Him* on His right and on His left. The LORD said, ‘Who will entice Ahab to go up and fall at Ramoth-gilead?’ *And one said this while another said that*. Then a spirit came forward and stood before the LORD and said, ‘I will entice him.’"

Micaiah could not have received this revelation merely through his own imagination. There is both a visual and audible component as he relates this message. I am unable to determine whether this was a dream or a vision, perhaps it was both? Nonthesis, Micaiah's response to Ahab was clearly articulated as an event, not merely his imagination. When God "spoke" to the prophets, He often did so in dreams. I do not think that was merely a projection of their imagination.

---

Having said all of this, the fact is, **we actually imagine everything** as a product of our mind.

Suppose we see a tree. We do not actually "see" that tree, because the light from that object is transmitted along our optic nerve (among many other things) to the brain, where bits and pieces of information are stored in disparate locations everywhere (don't ask me how). It is the *mind* that brings all of that data together such that we "see" the tree.

I too have wondered the same: Do dreams sometimes "have a connection" to the spiritual realm? It seems plausible, although I would caution that any special revelation, as with the prophets, has ceased (Jude. vs. 3). In other words, God has no additional information to convey that might have scriptural significance, other than perhaps to open our minds to a deeper interpretive appreciation for His Word.

We might also consider this:

> **2 Corinthians 4:16**: "Therefore we do not lose heart... our inner man is being renewed day by day."

Since we possess a clear spiritual component, it would make sense that there is at least some connection to the spirit world, however subtle that may be. When we pray to God as the faithful, we are told that God hears our prayers. And while we might usually vocalize them, that may be unnecessary (although I do not personally think so) since God knows all we think and imagine. (Our vocalization is probably only for our benefit.)

This is a difficult question. We know that the Devil tempts us. How does he do that? He seems to have some intimate knowledge of our thoughts, and perhaps has the ability to implant certain ideas in our minds (although he cannot make us do anything). Perhaps that, and the knowledge that God hears our prayers is as close to actual spiritual intervention as we might be able to discern.